# eliminate duplicates using dictionary in python

Tags: python, twitter, duplicates

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate tweets from a couchDB database. I want to eliminate the retweeted tweets by using the retweeted_status ID field. Heres is my code; it doesn't work and returns the error "string indices must be characters". Any help will be appreciated.

```
# initialize a dictionary of tweet ids
# the first time an id is found, put it into the dict as a key (with value 1 (not used))
uniqueIDs = {}

numtweets = len(search_results)
numdeleted = 0

for tweet in search_results:
    # find retweeted_status
    if 'retweeted_status' in tweet.keys():
        retweetID = [retweeted_status[id] for retweeted_status in tweet ['retweeted_status']]
        #tweetID = retweeted_status['id']
        # get the tweetid from the keys
        #tweetID = tweet['id']
        # if it is already in the id dictionary then delete this one
        if retweetID in uniqueIDs.keys():
            db.delete(tweet)
            numdeleted += 1
        # otherwise add it to the unique ids
        else:
            uniqueIDs[retweetID] = 1
    else:
        # reduce the count if we skipped one
        numtweets -= 1


print "Number of tweets at beginning = ", numtweets
print "Number of tweets deleted = ", numdeleted
```

Comment: `retweetID` is a `list`, not an `int`. This also means that it will never be found in the `uniqueIDs` dictionary, since `list` objects aren't hashable.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `retweetID` as a list, but then using it as a single value. Instead of using `[... for ... in ...]`, you should just loop through `tweet['retweeted_status']`. You'd have something like this:

```
if 'retweeted_status' in tweet:  # Note, don't need .keys()
    for retweedID in tweet['retweeted_status']:
        if retweetID in uniqueIDs:  # Again, don't need .keys()
            ...
        else:
            uniqueIDs[retweetID] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Ken. One clarification: I need to find duplicate IDs in the retweeted_status field, not the tweet's ID.  It's one more level down, ie. tweet -> retweeted_status-> id (for the retweeted status). I'll  add that ID to a dictionary in order to identify duplicates. Based on duplicated IDs for the retweeted status, the entire tweet should be deleted.
I tried this but doesn't work:
    for tweet in search_results:  
        if 'rewteeted_status' in tweet:   
            if 'id' in 'retweeted_status':
                retweetID = retweeted_status['id']

Answer (score 0):

```
 retweetID = [retweeted_status[id] for retweeted_status in tweet ['retweeted_status']]
```

The above line sets retweetID as a list. May be the following is what you wanted to do.

```
for tweet in search_results:
    # find retweeted_status
    if 'retweeted_status' in tweet.keys():
        retweetIDs = [retweeted_status[id] for retweeted_status in tweet ['retweeted_status']]
        #tweetID = retweeted_status['id']
        # get the tweetid from the keys
        #tweetID = tweet['id']
        # if it is already in the id dictionary then delete this one
        for tweet_id in retweetIDs:
            if retweetID in uniqueIDs.keys():
                db.delete(tweet)
                numdeleted += 1
        # otherwise add it to the unique ids
            else:
                uniqueIDs[tweet_id] = 1
    else:
        # reduce the count if we skipped one
        numtweets -= 1
```

This checks for the presence of each of those retweet ids in your uniqueIds. If you just want the unique tweet ids, then instead of dictionary, you can use a set too.

```
unique_ids = set()
for tweet in search_results:
    if 'retweeted_status' not in tweet.keys():
         continue
    retweetIDs = [retweeted_status[id] for retweeted_status in tweet ['retweeted_status']]
    unique_ids.update(retweetIds)
```